# Aapt2 exception even after disabling it

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt, aapt2

I have an old android project that is having compilation problems. I've added a gradle.properties file to root with a single line:

```
android.enableAapt2 = false
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because I've disabled aapt2 and it still seems to be using it. In addition, I've checked every log I can find with no additional information found on what is actually breaking.

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question, the build is giving you an AAPT error, which might be coming from AAPT(1), not just AAPT2, that's why disabling AAPT2 doesn't "fix" it.

Secondly, disabling AAPT2 is not a solution. AAPT2 is telling you there's something wrong with your files. It fails the build early so that your app doesn't crash at run-time (which AAPT would silently allow).

Lastly, it's possible that you modified something in between the builds or that it didn't build in the past either. A way to figure out what the problem is, is to check the logs. If you're having trouble finding them in Android Studio (they will be in different places for different versions of Android Studio, Android Gradle Plugin and Gradle), an easy way to generate it is to go to the Terminal window in Android Studio and run `"gradlew clean assembleDebug"`. The errors from AAPT/AAPT2 should be just above the stacktrace.